# Разумно ли предположение о хранении данных в одной таблице?

Tags: база-данных

Как спроектировать в БД для хранения элементов меню с неограниченными сложениями (много родителей - много потомков и тд)? Есть вариант хранить все в одной таблице, есть вариант в нескольких. Как правильно с точки зрения проектирования? Если данные хранятся в 1 таблице, то не будет ли на нее нагрузка больше, чем, допустим, в нескольких?

Comment: нет никакой точки зрения проэктирования. делайте оба варианта забивайте реальными данными и проверяйте производительность. это и будет вашим ответом на вопрос. несколько таблиц более интуитивно понятны для восприятия. с другой стороны если много обращений то думаю лучше хранить в одной таблице + еще сделать так чтоб она постоянно висела в памяти.

Answer (score 2):

Много родителей + много потомков это ад. Это уже не обычное дерево, а полноценный граф, и если дерево sql-em обходить ещё кое-как, то граф очень не советую. Я пробовал :)

Мой совет - откажитесь от "много родителей" сразу. И храните вашу менюшку в одной табличке.

И почитайте вот это:
[What are the Options for Storing Hierarchical Data in a Relational Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)

Comment: не хотел бы вас разочаровывать, но "A Tree is a Cyclic Connected Graph."

Comment: Дерево это конечно граф но уж точно не циклический а ровно наоборот.

Answer (score 1):

Делайте в одной таблице**.**